# Zul apply Composer from java code

Tags: zk

Is it possible to apply Composer from java code?
As I know ZK have option to apply Composer from ZUL.

```
    <window apply="foo.MyComposer">
```

But if we have some wizard that consists of multiple steps action handling can be a problem....

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
Window window = new Window();
Composer composer = new MyComposer();
window.setApply(composer);
```

Comment: and how to set zul after that?

Comment: A word of advice: when you create a component programmatically you should not use a Composer object. Just use listeners

Comment: What do you mean by "to set zul after that"?

Comment: Window class in ZK doesnt have a setApply method.